# Inserting PART I and PART II Dividers into the Listing of Endnotes in TOC

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, footnotes, subdividing, endnotes

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote\endnote
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{endnote}{chapter}  % Reset endnote numbering everyv%new chapter
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\let\latexchapter\chapter
\makeatletter  %changes the catcode of @ to 11
\renewcommand\enoteheading{% changes being made here
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
  \latexchapter*{\notesname\markboth{NOTES}{}}
  \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip
  \let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue
}
\makeatother %changes the catcode of @ back to 12

\usepackage{xparse}

\RenewDocumentCommand {\chapter}{som}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}
  {\latexchapter*{#3}%
   \setcounter{endnote}{0}%
   \addtoendnotes{%
     \noexpand\enotedivision{\noexpand\subsection}
       {\unexpanded{#3}}}%
  }
  {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
     {\latexchapter{#3}}
     {\latexchapter[#2]{#3}}%
   \addtoendnotes{%
     \noexpand\enotedivision{\noexpand\subsection}
       {\chaptername\ \thechapter. \unexpanded{#3}}}%
  }%
}
\makeatletter
\def\enotedivision#1#2{\@ifnextchar\enotedivision{}{#1{#2}}}
\makeatletter


\usepackage{lettrine}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\setlength{\DefaultFindent}{0em}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{.17em}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\usefont{U}{yinit}{m}{n}}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{-0.67}
\definecolor{olivegreen}{cmyk}{0.64,0,0.95,0.40}

\begin{document}
\LARGE

%The Table of Contents
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents.}
\tableofcontents


\chapter*{INTRODUCTION}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{INTRODUCTION.}}
\lettrine{\color{olivegreen}{T}}{\textbf{\color{olivegreen}his}} is the Introduction. Some words.\footnote{an endnote.} Some words.\footnote{an endnote.} Some words.


% PART I BEGINS HERE.

\chapter*{Chapter I}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 4pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chapter I.}}
\lettrine{\color{olivegreen}{T}}{\textbf{\color{olivegreen}his}} is Chapter I. of \textbf{PART I}. Some words.\footnote{an endnote.}Some words.\footnote{an endnote.}Some words.\footnote{an endnote.}


\chapter*{Chapter II}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 4pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chapter II.}}
\lettrine{\color{olivegreen}{T}}{\textbf{\color{olivegreen}his}} is Chapter II. Some words.\footnote{An endnote.}Some words.\footnote{An endnote.}Some words.\footnote{An endnote.}Some words.\footnote{An endnote.}Some words.\footnote{An endnote.}


% PART II BEGINS HERE.

\chapter*{Chapter I}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 4pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chapter I.}}
\lettrine{\color{olivegreen}{T}}{\textbf{\color{olivegreen}his}} is Chapter I. of \textbf{PART II}.\footnote{An endnote.}Some words.\footnote{An endnote.}Some words.\footnote{An endnote.}Some words.\footnote{An endnote.}Some words.\footnote{An endnote.}Some words.\footnote{An endnote.} 


\chapter*{} 
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 4pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Endnotes.}}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{Endnotes} % Renames `Notes' to `Endnotes'
\addtoendnotes{\unexpanded{\enotedivision{}{}}}
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

which produces the TABLE OF CONTENTS:

[image]

As you can see, the Endnotes delineation in the TOC lists "Chapter I" twice---the first occurrence  being the Chapter I associated with PART I of the document; the other, pertaining to PART II. I would like to insert **PART I** (coming before the first Chapter I) and **PART II** (coming before the second Chapter I) dividers (with appropriate space) into the Endnotes listing in the TOC to make the distinction between the two sets of chapter listings clear.

QUESTION: How may I accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not fond of the "starred-sectioning-command"-`\addcontentsline`-policy exhibited in your code. ;-)

Be that as it may.

You can patch the `\part`-command in the same way as you patched the `\chapter`-command.

In order to make sure the corresponding `\enotedivision` s are carried out, append, e.g., `\relax` to them.

In your code the mechanism for creating subsection-level-entries in the table of contents is (ab?)used for displaying chapter-level entries within the toc's listing of endnotes .

For displaying part-level entries within the toc's listing of endnotes you can analogously (ab?)use the mechanism for creating section-level-entries in the table of contents.

I assume you don't wish dotted lines leading to page-numbers with these entries.

Therefore I borrowed the code of `\l@section` and `\@dottedtocline` and created a command `\l@myhandmadepart` and have the patched `\part`-command's `\addtoendnotes` also add `\addtocontents`-directives for locally letting `\l@section` equal to `\l@myhandmadepart`.

I don't know whether this works out when hyperref is in use as well.

---

Edit in January 26, 2022:

As [requested in comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631292/inserting-part-i-and-part-ii-dividers-into-the-listing-of-endnotes-in-toc/631455#comment1574771_631455) I modified the code:

Now you have a command `\endnotepart` which takes the same arguments as the command `\part`.

The command `\endnotepart` obeys three `\if...`-switches:

- `\endnotepartDoDocumentPartDivisiontrue`/`\endnotepartDoDocumentPartDivisionfalse`:
  This switch toggles whether whether `\endnotepart` shall do the `\part`-division in the document for you , too.
  If this switch is true, `\endnotepart` also does `\part` for you.
- `\endnotepartPartsInEndnotestrue`/`\endnotepartPartsInEndnotesfalse`:
  If this switch is true, `\endnotepart` adds headlines for parts within the endnotes-section.
- `\endnotepartPartsInEndnotesToclistingtrue`/`\endnotepartPartsInEndnotesToclistingfalse`:
  If this switch is true, `\endnotepart` adds entries for parts in the toc's listing of endnotes.
  I suppose this switch is the most interesting one for you.

```latex
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote\endnote
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{endnote}{chapter}  % Reset endnote numbering everyv%new chapter
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%===============================================================================
%  The \if-switches...
%===============================================================================
% Toggle whether \endnotepart shall do the \part-command as well:
\newif\ifendnotepartDoDocumentPartDivision
%\endnotepartDoDocumentPartDivisiontrue
\endnotepartDoDocumentPartDivisionfalse
%
% Toggle whether \endnotepart shall add headlines for parts within the 
% endnotes-section as well:
\newif\ifendnotepartPartsInEndnotes
%\endnotepartPartsInEndnotestrue
\endnotepartPartsInEndnotesfalse
%
% Toggle whether \endnotepart shall add entries for parts in the toc's listing
% of endnotes as well - I suppose this is the most interesting switch for you:
\newif\ifendnotepartPartsInEndnotesToclisting
\endnotepartPartsInEndnotesToclistingtrue
%\endnotepartPartsInEndnotesToclistingfalse
%
%===============================================================================

\let\latexchapter\chapter
\makeatletter  %changes the catcode of @ to 11
\newcommand\l@myhandmadepart{%
  \@myundottedtocline {1}{1.5em}{2.3em}%
}
\newcommand\@myundottedtocline[5]{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth\else 
    \vskip\z@\@plus.2\p@
    {%
      \leftskip#2\relax
      \rightskip\@tocrmarg
      \parfillskip-\rightskip
      \parindent#2\relax
      \@afterindenttrue
      \interlinepenalty\@M
      \leavevmode
      \@tempdima#3\relax
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \null\nobreak\hskip-\leftskip 
      {#4}\nobreak\hfill\nobreak\null
      \par
    }%
  \fi 
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\sectiontomyhandmadepart{%
  \let\l@section=\l@myhandmadepart
}%
\renewcommand\enoteheading{% changes being made here
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
  \latexchapter*{\notesname\markboth{NOTES}{}}
  \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip
  \let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue
}
\makeatother %changes the catcode of @ back to 12

\usepackage{xparse}

\RenewDocumentCommand {\chapter}{som}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}%
  {\latexchapter*{#3}%
   \setcounter{endnote}{0}%
   \addtoendnotes{%
     \unexpanded{\enotedivision{\subsection}{#3}}%
   }%
  }%
  {\IfNoValueTF{#2}%
     {\latexchapter{#3}}%
     {\latexchapter[#2]{#3}}%
   \addtoendnotes{%
     \unexpanded{\enotedivision{\subsection}}%
       {\chaptername\ \thechapter. \unexpanded{#3}}}%
  }%
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\endnotepart}{som}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}%
  {\ifendnotepartDoDocumentPartDivision\part*{#3}\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#3}\fi
   \setcounter{endnote}{0}%
   \addtoendnotes{%
     \ifendnotepartPartsInEndnotes
       \unexpanded{%
       \addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\sectiontomyhandmadepart}%
       \enotedivision{\section}{#3}}%
       \relax
       \noexpand\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}%
     \else
       \ifendnotepartPartsInEndnotesToclisting
         \unexpanded{%
         \addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\sectiontomyhandmadepart}%
         \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#3}%
         \addtocontents}{toc}{\endgroup}%
       \fi
     \fi
   }%
  }%
  {\IfNoValueTF{#2}%
     {\ifendnotepartDoDocumentPartDivision\part{#3}\fi}%
     {\ifendnotepartDoDocumentPartDivision\part[#2]{#3}\fi}%
   \addtoendnotes{%
     \ifendnotepartPartsInEndnotes
       \unexpanded{%
       \addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\sectiontomyhandmadepart}%
       \enotedivision{\section}}%
         {\partname\ \thepart. \unexpanded{#3}}%
       \relax
       \noexpand\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}%
     \else
       \ifendnotepartPartsInEndnotesToclisting
         \unexpanded{%
         \addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\sectiontomyhandmadepart}%
         \addcontentsline{toc}{section}}{\partname\ \thepart. \unexpanded{#3}}%
         \noexpand\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}%
       \fi
     \fi
   }%
  }%
}%

\makeatletter
\def\enotedivision#1#2{\@ifnextchar\enotedivision{}{#1{#2}}}
\makeatletter

\usepackage{lettrine}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{2}
\setlength{\DefaultFindent}{0em}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{.17em}
\renewcommand*{\DefaultLraise}{-0.05}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\usefont{U}{yinit}{m}{n}}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{.1}
\definecolor{olivegreen}{cmyk}{0.64,0,0.95,0.40}

\begin{document}
\LARGE

%The Table of Contents
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents.}
\tableofcontents


\chapter*{INTRODUCTION}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{INTRODUCTION.}}
\lettrine{\color{olivegreen}{T}}{\textbf{\color{olivegreen}his}} is the Introduction. Some words.\footnote{an endnote.} Some words.\footnote{an endnote.} Some words.


% PART I BEGINS HERE.
\endnotepart*{First part}

\chapter*{Chapter I}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 4pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chapter I.}}
\lettrine{\color{olivegreen}{T}}{\textbf{\color{olivegreen}his}} is Chapter I. of \textbf{PART I}. Some words.\footnote{an endnote.}Some words.\footnote{an endnote.}Some words.\footnote{an endnote.}


\chapter*{Chapter II}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 4pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chapter II.}}
\lettrine{\color{olivegreen}{T}}{\textbf{\color{olivegreen}his}} is Chapter II. Some words.\footnote{An endnote.}Some words.\footnote{An endnote.}Some words.\footnote{An endnote.}Some words.\footnote{An endnote.}Some words.\footnote{An endnote.}


% PART II BEGINS HERE.
\endnotepart*{Second part}

\chapter*{Chapter I}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 4pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Chapter I.}}
\lettrine{\color{olivegreen}{T}}{\textbf{\color{olivegreen}his}} is Chapter I. of \textbf{PART II}.\footnote{An endnote.}Some words.\footnote{An endnote.}Some words.\footnote{An endnote.}Some words.\footnote{An endnote.}Some words.\footnote{An endnote.}Some words.\footnote{An endnote.} 


\chapter*{} 
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 4pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Endnotes.}}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{Endnotes} % Renames `Notes' to `Endnotes'
\addtoendnotes{\unexpanded{\enotedivision{}{}}}
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this super effort; however, would you be able to prevent the 4 additional pages from appearing within the document text: ((i) PART I (ii) the blank page associated with it (iii) PART II (iv)  the blank page associated with it? The reason is that I only need the PART I and PART II to appear within the Endnotes listing in the TOC --- as you have accomplished. But the division into parts within the document itself I have already taken care of.  Sorry for the additional request, but I am not familiar enough with your code to take care of it myself.  Thanks again.

Comment: @mlchristians I modified the code and introduced a command `\endnotepart` which obeys three `\if`-switches  so that you can toggle whether `\endnotepart` shall do `\part` as well, whether `\endnotepart` shall add part-headings within the endnotes-section of the document as well, whether `\endnotepart` shall add part-entries within the endnotes-listing of the table of contents as well. I suppose you need to toggle the first two switches to "false" and the last switch to "true".

Comment: Thank you again for your effort; however, I wanted the PART I and PART II to appear *only* within the endnotes listing of the TOC. Not anywhere else in the TOC nor anywhere else in the document. I know this seemingly simple objective is much more difficult than it appears. Nevertheless, I figured I would ask---but perhaps, there is not a way to do what I am looking for on a single compilation. I thank you for trying though.

Comment: @mlchristians With my example toggle the switches as follows: `\endnotepartDoDocumentPartDivisionfalse` and `\endnotepartPartsInEndnotesfalse` and `\endnotepartPartsInEndnotesToclistingtrue`  and compile several times and see if the result is what you desire.

Comment: As is, the program runs without error for me. However, trying to get it to produce only what I am looking for always results in errors for me. As I suggested before, perhaps a program does not yet exit which adds, in one "fell swoop", PART I and PART II *only* to the Endnotes listing of the TOC, so Ithink I  will have to figure something else out. Thank you again.

Comment: @mlchristians I just edited my example once more and toggled the `\if..`-switches introduced in my previous edit. Please tell precisely in which aspect it does not deliver the output you need. And also please precisely describe the circumstances where errors occur. (Probably that would be a follow-up-question to this one.)

Comment: The problem is with me, I'm sure. I do not understand what is meant by "toggle" and so forth, and so, I would be at a loss to adequately explain the errors. Other than producing indices or updating the TOC, I am familiar only with running LaTeX programs once. Sorry, but you are not talking with an expert here. I hope to post an alternative question later today.

Comment: @mlchristians Assume you have created a new `\if..`-conditional via `\newif\iffoo`. If the switch `\footrue` is applied, `\iffoo...\else..\fi` will take the `\if..`-branch/true-branch. If the switch `\foofalse` is applied, `\iffoo...\else..\fi` will take the `\else..`-branch/false-branch.  Toggling means changing from `\footrue` to `\foofalse` or from `\foofalse` to `\footrue`. The effect is switching which branch the `\iffoo..\else..\fi`-conditional will take.

Comment: Now, this seems to work for me on the first try. Thank you. I hope to try to assimilate the technicalities a little later. Many thanks!